# Parse currency values from CSV, convert numerical suffixes for Million and Billion

Tags: r, currency, read.csv, suffix

I'm curious if there's any sort of out of the box functions in R that can handle this.

I have a CSV file that I am reading into a data frame using read.csv.  One of the columns in the CSV contains currency values in the format of

```
Currency
--------
$1.2M
$3.1B
N/A
```

I would like to convert those into more usable numbers that calculations can be performed against, so it would look like this:

```
Currency
----------
1200000
3100000000
NA
```

My initial thoughts were to somehow subset the dataframe into 3 parts based on rows that contain *M, *B, or N/A.  Then use gsub to replace the $ and M/B, then multiply the remaining number by 1000000 or 1000000000, and finally rejoin the 3 subsets back into 1 data frame.

However I'm curious if there's a simpler way to handle this sort of conversion in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `gsubfn` to replace the 'B', 'M' with 'e+9', 'e+6' and convert to `numeric` (`as.numeric`).

```
is.na(v1) <- v1=='N/A'
options(scipen=999)
library(gsubfn)
as.numeric(gsubfn('([A-Z]|\\$)', list(B='e+9', M='e+6',"$"=""),v1)) 
#[1]    1200000 3100000000         NA
```

EDIT: Modified based on @nicola's suggestion

#### data

```
v1 <- c('$1.2M', '$3.1B', 'N/A')
```

Comment: Since you are using `gsubfn`, wouldn't  `as.numeric(gsubfn('([A-Z]|\\$)', list(B='e+9', M='e+6',"$"=""),v1))` be simpler? No need to `sapply`, `unname`, `eval` and `parse` some text and neither to set `NA` beforehand (since `as.numeric` will do it by itself).

Comment: @nicola Yes, it is simpler.  I wonder why I used `sapply`.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! that was exactly what i was looking for.  I did however drop the "is.na(v1) <- v1=='N/A'" as I realized I could do this with read.csv using the this option: na.strings="n/a"

Answer (score 1):

Another way, is using a `for-loop` :

```
x <- c("1.2M", "2.5M", "1.6B", "N/A")
x <- ifelse(x=="N/A", NA, x)
num <- as.numeric(strsplit(x, "[^0-9.]+"))

for(i in 1:length(x)) {
 if(grepl('M', x[i]))
  print(prod(num[i], 1000000))
  else
  print(prod(num[i], 100000000))
}

# [1] 1200000
# [1] 2500000
# [1] 1.6e+08
# [1] NA
```

Comment: thank you for the advice, though I am doing my best to "break" myself of the habbit of using loops.  R seems to discourage them, and i'm trying to get a feel for the :"R way" of doing things.  I do however fully understand where you are coming from as most other scripting languages would handle this sort of thing with a loop :)

Comment: @user3246693 yes, that is true! Loops are not recommended in R.